# Projectile Not Correctly Inheriting Parent Velocity (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am trying to fire projectiles from a player who is moving at very high speeds. The issue is that the bullets do not seem to inherit the angular velocity. If the player is moving in a straight line at 500 U/s, then the bullet correctly inherits that velocity and adds its own speed onto that:

```
GameObject bullet = Instantiate(projectile, gun.transform.position, gun.transform.rotation);
bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = r.velocity + bullet.transform.forward *bulletSpeed;
```

However, if the player is turning really quickly, it does not inherit the rotational velocity, and the bullet looks like it veers off to the side.

How can I implement this? I tried assigning the angular velocity of the player to the bullet, but this just caused the bullet to spin while moving in the same direction.

Some extra details:

- I am using rigidbody.MoveRotation() to rotate my player, but I manually calculated angularVelocity to assign it to the bullet
- I tried moving the player with AddTorque(), but could not produce any results with the bullets

Comment: if you define bullet as a child object of gun then if the gun moves and/or rotate then the bullet will also move with respect to gun. I think that is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem is that the projectile isn't part of the physics simulation until the moment you create and launch it, meaning the rotation of the player up to that point will not be able to influence its movement. I suppose this could work if you created the projectile at the start, attached it to the gun with a weak joint, then broke the joint and added to its velocity when it was fired - but it really would be simpler if you just "faked" it.

### Applying Circular Motion

This is similar to a classic circular motion example you'd find in a physics textbook. When your bullet travels in a circle around the player (inside the gun), its normal path (if released) would be tangent to the circular path around the player. So when the bullet is fired (and hence released from the circular path), that angular velocity of the player would translate into a linear velocity of the bullet. Here's a simple diagram I put together that represents the situation with a ball on a string, being spun in a circle:

[image]

### Getting the Tangential Velocity of the Bullet

You don't want to be applying any kind of angular velocity to the projectile after it has been launched - as you saw, this will only spin the projectile on its own axis. Rather, you want to apply an additional velocity vector to the projectile, which is tangent to the rotation of the player (and perpendicular to the facing of the bullet). So how do we do this?

Well, as per [this website](http://www.softschools.com/formulas/physics/tangential_velocity_formula/25/), the formula for tangential velocity at any point on something spinning in a circle is:

> velocity = angularVelocity x radius

*A key point to remember is that the angularVelocity is in radians, not degrees.*

So, let's put this all together. Here's a general idea of how you might code this:

```
FireGun() {
    // Assumes the current class has access to the rotation rate of the player
    float bulletAngularVelocityRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad(rotationRateDegrees)

    // The radius of the circular motion is the distance between the bullet
    // spawn point and the player's axis of rotation
    float bulletRotationRadius =
        (r.transform.position - gun.transform.position).magnitude;

    GameObject bullet =
        Instantiate(projectile, gun.transform.position, gun.transform.rotation);

    // You may need to reverse the sign here, since bullet.transform.right
    // may be opposite of the rotation
    Vector3 bulletTangentialVelocity =
        bulletAngularVelocityRad * bulletRotationRadius * bullet.transform.right;

    // Now we can just add on bulletTangentialVelocity as a component
    // vector to the velocity
    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity =
        r.velocity + bullet.transform.forward * bulletSpeed + bulletTangentialVelocity;
}
```

Hope this helps! It's never a bad idea to read up on some basic kinematics/mechanics when you're working with game physics, since sometimes relying on the game physics is actually more complicated than just devising your own solution.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I also found that multiplying the angle of the angular velocity at the point of the spawn point by the rotation of the player worked nicely, both of these solutions are similar.